# Consumir api privada en JavaScript mediante promesas

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, promesas

estoy comenzando con el tema de las api y no logro extraer los datos e imprimirlos en un html para luego darle estilos.
se trata de una api (tengo el url con los datos de acceso) que me genera un json con una lista de los datos de una funeraria, donde tengo que extraer datos como: nombre, apellido, imagen, y url del memorial.

Hasta ahora tengo este código, pero no se que estoy haciendo mal:
js

```
const API_URL = "https://api.dominio.group/memorials.json?user_email=nombre@hotmail.com&user_token=HG2H5JJKL2O1Ñ3&q[starts_at_gteq]=2022-12-01";

const getData = (apiURL) => {
    return fetch(apiURL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => { imDatos(json) })
    .catch(error => {console.error('Error: ', error) })
}


const imDatos = (data) => {
    let html = '';
    data.forEach(c => {
        html += '<div class="col"';
            html += '<div class="card" style="width: 13rem;">'
                html += '<img src="${c.image_url}" class="card-img-top">'
                html += '<div class="card-body">'
                    html += '<h5 class="card-title">${c.last_name}</h5>'

                html += '</div>'


            html += '</div>'
        html += '</div>'
    });
    document.getElementById('infoCharacters').innerHTML = html;
    
}

getData(API_URL);
```

el resultado que me arroja es:  net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND en el URL de la imagen

[image: asi]

aqui dejo la estructura del json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 32749,
    "first_name": "Cinthia",
    "last_name": "Flores",
    "image": {
      "url": "https://link",
      "thumb": {
        "url": "https://link"
      }
    },
    "religion_id": null,
    "religion": null,
    "room": {
      "id": 56,
      "name": "Sala 1",
      "branch_id": 25,
      "company_id": 16,
      "code": "57MXR",
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "2018-05-03T17:35:43.484-03:00",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-03T17:35:43.484-03:00"
    },
    "room_id": 56,
    "branch": {
      "id": 25,
      "name": "CASA CENTRAL",
      "address": "LA RIOJA 267",
      "phone": "3874218329",
      "state_id": 16,
      "company_id": 16,
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "2018-05-03T17:35:27.403-03:00",
      "updated_at": "2018-05-03T17:41:35.604-03:00",
      "has_ecommerce": false
    },
    "died_at": "2022-12-09T00:00:00.000-03:00",
    "starts_at": "2022-12-09T12:00:00.000-03:00",
    "ends_at": "2022-12-10T13:00:00.000-03:00",
    "price": "95.0",
    "type_of_burial": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Cremación",
      "deleted_at": null,
      "created_at": "2017-09-04T18:58:37.913-03:00",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-04T18:58:37.913-03:00"
    },
    "contact_email": null,
    "type_of_burial_id": 1,
    "burial_address": "Divina Misericordia",
    "burial_at": "2022-12-10T14:00:00.000-03:00",
    "code": "59DBA",
    "display_code_in_room": true,
    "slug": "cinthia-flores",
    "token": "Xh5nwWsAmuhfCEd-Hkxb",
    "contact_phone": null,
    "created_at": "2022-12-09T12:11:50.613-03:00",
    "updated_at": "2022-12-09T12:11:50.613-03:00",
    "youtube_video_id": "",
    "youtube_video_url": "",
    "notes": null,
    "has_automated_messages": null,
    "image_url": "https://link.jpg"
    },
    "company": {
      "logo_url": "https://link.png",
      "display_messages": true,
      "display_cross_in_name": null,
      "background_image_url": "https://link.jpg",
      "primary_color": "#3ca6f1",
      "secondary_color": "#0081d3",
      "custom_signature": "",
      "country_code": null
    },
    "memorial_url": "https://link",
    "memorial_private_url": "https://link"
  },
]
```

Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` significa que la url de la imagen no es correcta.

Comment: si, pero el json estan correctos los link, aqui en el ejemplo cambie las url pero en el original si salen bien. Sera que estoy haciendo algo mal? porque no imprime los datos del api, este es la url que toma <https://prnt.sc/od4Dv7uqHfA->

Comment: En el ejemplo que muestras la url de la imagen apunta al sistema de archivos local. Si el backend y el frontend no están en la misma pc eso no funcionará.

Comment: Si quieres usar string templates, para usar los parametros con ${parametro} debes poner el  string con comilla simple invertida y no con comilla simple normal... es decir no así `'hola ${param}'` sino así `\`hola ${param}\``. Puede ser esa la razón por la que el dato de last_name y el de la url queden malos. Ah, y el primer div no lo estás cerrando al final del string.

Comment: @Pipe Muchísimas gracias, probé con lo que me dijiste en cambiar a comilla simple normal a invertida donde uso los parámetros y así me los imprimió bien en el html, ahora si, el código esta funcionando correctamente. Gracias por tu ayuda bro